# Oracle procedure to increment string data type and store it as one of the column in table

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

I need to take the max value of the column id which starts with AB from Table A
I have a Table B where I need to update the column values max value +1 for all the rows present in Table B.

For example If I get the max value from Table A as AB1500, and Table B has 20 records and various columns, I need to populate from AB1501 to AB1520 for the records in Table B for the ORG_ID column.
Issue: For loop not able to write data into the TABLE B

Table A:

| ORG_ID | ORG_NAME |
| --- | --- |
| AE500 | Google |
| AB1500 | Amazon |
| AB1200 | Apple |

Table B: Here For the available records i need to increment from max of AB from Table A

| Country | Country_ID | ORG_ID |
| --- | --- | --- |
| US | 10 | AB1501 |
| UK | 11 | AB1502 |
| FRANCE | 12 | AB1503 |

```
Create or replace procedure proc_incr(
    v_org_id  IN TableB.org_id%TYPE
)
    v_max_number NUMBER;
    v_max_org_id VARCHAR2(20);
    v_max_var    VARCHAR2(20);
    v_temp       VARCHAR2(20);
    v_count      NUMBER;
    
    begin
           select max(Table A.org_id)
           into v_max_org_id
           from TableA where org_id like 'AB%';
           select count(*) 
           into v_count
           from Table B;
           select regexp_substr(v_max_org_id, '\d+')
           into v_max_number
           from dual;
           select regexp_substr(v_max_org_id, '\D+')
           into v_max_var
           from dual;
         // For Loop to write data to Table B
           for i in 1 .. (v_count) LOOP
             v_temp := v_max_number+i;
             v_max_org_id := v_max_var||v_temp;
             v_org_id := v_max_org_id;
           End LOOP;
           commit;
    END proc_incr;
```

Comment: But you do not write the data into Table B in your code. What is the meaning of this statement: "For loop not able to write data into the TABLE B"? What is the issue with it?

Comment: Hi @astentx,   I am trying to write the data for the 20 records present in Table B from AB1501 to AB1520, unable to achieve it with the for loop. any help is highly appreciated.

Comment: Add your sample data please. (not as a image)

Comment: What is your input and what is your expected output? Your `table_b` values appear to already be incremented by 1 so is that your expected output? If so, what do you start with? If it is your starting data then what do you expect the output to be?

Comment: Also, you probably do not want to use `MAX(org_id)` as it is a string and `AB900` is greater than `AB1500` when you do a string comparison.

Answer (score 0):

Sample data:

```
SQL> SELECT * FROM tablea;

ORG_ID
------
AB1500
CD1234

SQL> SELECT * FROM tableb;

ORG_ID NAME
------ ------
xxxxxx Little
       Foot
       Mahe
```

Your code, slightly fixed; you didn't perform any update, so I presume that's why you had an "issue"

> For loop not able to write data into the TABLE B

Note the cursor for the `tableb` table; it is used to update current row fetched by it.

```
SQL> DECLARE
  2     v_max_number  NUMBER;
  3     v_max_org_id  VARCHAR2 (20);
  4     v_max_var     VARCHAR2 (20);
  5
  6     CURSOR curb IS
  7        SELECT org_id, name
  8          FROM tableb
  9        FOR UPDATE;
 10
 11     cbr           curb%ROWTYPE;
 12     i             NUMBER := 1;
 13  BEGIN
 14     SELECT MAX (tablea.org_id)
 15       INTO v_max_org_id
 16       FROM tablea
 17      WHERE org_id LIKE 'AB%';
 18
 19     SELECT REGEXP_SUBSTR (v_max_org_id, '\d+') INTO v_max_number FROM DUAL;
 20
 21     SELECT REGEXP_SUBSTR (v_max_org_id, '\D+') INTO v_max_var FROM DUAL;
 22
 23     -- For Loop to write data to Table B
 24     OPEN curb;
 25
 26     LOOP
 27        FETCH curb INTO cbr;
 28
 29        EXIT WHEN curb%NOTFOUND;
 30
 31        v_max_org_id := v_max_var || TO_CHAR (v_max_number + i);
 32
 33        UPDATE tableb
 34           SET org_id = v_max_org_id
 35         WHERE CURRENT OF curb;
 36
 37        i := i + 1;
 38     END LOOP;
 39  END;
 40  /

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.

SQL> SELECT * FROM tableb;

ORG_ID NAME
------ ------
AB1501 Little
AB1502 Foot
AB1503 Mahe

SQL>
```

Comment: Hi need your help, does the select query  SELECT MAX (tablea.org_id)
        INTO v_max_org_id
        FROM tablea
       WHERE org_id LIKE 'AB%';  always fetches the maximum value that begins with AB

Comment: I don't think so.